# philips MFD 6050 printer installation ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing

I'm experiencing difficulties with the installation of the Philips MFD 6050 printer/scanner on a Lenovo laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit.

Official drivers can be downloaded [here](http://www.p4c.philips.com/cgi-bin/dcbint/cpindex.pl?slg=en&scy=hr&mid=Link_Software&ctn=LFF6050/INB). They were for Ubuntu 7.10 originally. I stumbled upon [this](http://markmail.org/message/ppqjtpn4loohzvx3#query:+page:1+mid:ta5mjffjr6kpusjw+state:results) forum threat, where someone described a problem similar to the one I'm having.

Following the suggested solution steps there:

1. change the install script to link the correct library like so:

   `ln -sf /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.9 /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5`
2. install the printer selecting the installed ppd file

Only gets me so far as that computer and printer are communicating (printer is 'starting up' if I print, but it always aborts before even touching the paper), but I don't actually get to print anything.

- I'm new to Ubuntu. If someone could point out some help it would be greatly appreciated.